# Group of quasi isometries of a given group

Tags: reference-request, geometric-group-theory

I'm looking for any sources calculating and describing properties of groups of quasi-isometry of finitely generated groups.Thank you for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the book of "Geometric Group theory: an introduction" by Clara Loh on page number 81